# Get Column Comments Multiple Tables/Left Join

Tags: php, mysql, comments

SO i am wondering if it is possible to get the information schema for mutliple tables in one query. Right now I have the following:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_COMMENT FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = ?"
```

This works fine if I am just getting comments from 1 table. I am wondering if there is  way to get them for multiple tables such as this:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_COMMENT FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE    
table_name1 = ? && table_name2 = ?"
```

or by using some left join logic etc. Thank you for any help.

Comment: I think queries against the information schema are symptomatic of poor design- and doubly so for queries that need to hit multiple tables

Answer (score 0):

Here we can use MySQL **IN** operator 
Try like this

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_COMMENT FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE table_name in (?,? )
```